# laravel runs increment method multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, increment

I have a function where users cancel their withdraw requests.
it works like this:

1. It checks whether the user has such a withdrawal request.
2. deletes the user's withdrawal request.
3. He adds the amount in the withdrawal request back to his balance.

I pass data to this function with an ajax request. When I run the ajax request in a loop, the amount that should be added to the user's balance is added more than once.

my php function:

```
public function cancel_withdraw(Request $request){
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'withdraw_id' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);
    $withdraw=Withdraw::where('user_id',Auth::id())
    ->where('id',$request->withdraw_id)
    ->whereNull('status')
    ->first();

    $withdraw->delete();

    Wallet::where('user_id',Auth::id())->increment($withdraw->coin,$withdraw->amount);
    return response()->json(['message'=>'Successfully Deleted!','errors' => ['']]);                        
}
```

my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        let i = 0;
        while (i < 100) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url('cancel_withdraw') }}",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: "_token={{ csrf_token() }}&withdraw_id="+withdraw_id,
            success: function(data) {},
            error: function(data){}
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        i++;
        } 
});
```

Comment: _When I run the ajax request in a loop, the amount that should be added to the user's balance is added more than once_ - Well yeah, because it's a loop. Call your function once and you'll have just one update?

Comment: Can a malicious user try the same thing?
  I would add the same amount to your account more than once.

Comment: This is a transaction operation, I don't want it to work on the second request(i am deleting it)

Comment: That would depend on the level of security you have implemented on your API. If you want to limit the number of transations that can be performed, you need to define that logic somehow (maybe rate limiting by time or status of the transaction).

Comment: I use a minute-based rate limiter, but all requests arrive in the same second.

Answer (score -1):

your method error is that. you can'y call coin||amoun column after you delete the data!
you have to change yor method like this:

```
    Wallet::where('user_id',Auth::id())->increment($withdraw->coin,$withdraw->amount);

$withdraw->delete();

return ...
```

Comment: calling `delete` on a model instance doesn't flush it's attributes ... that would make the `deleted` event not very useful if the model instance didn't retain its attributes

Comment: It works the way I do. Also it has nothing to do with the issue.